# How to deploy Ember CLI fastboot app for production?

Tags: javascript, express, ember.js, ember-cli

I prepared an ember-cli project that gets api from express server. Then I added fastboot to using the command:

> ember install ember-cli-fastboot

After that, all the links began to be rendered on the server. Tell me, how do I run this in production?
If I run **ember build** and load the project from the dist folder (via express route), the application opens like a usual SPA, and the child pages do not reload, and are not accessible for **curl**. That is, it behaves like a usual SPA.
Please tell me how to run it? Should I run it in production as it is, withowt build, i.e. from **ember-cli** folder, using **ember serve**?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to serve an Ember FastBoot application in production is currently using the [Ember FastBoot App Server](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-app-server#ember-fastboot-app-server).

Ember FastBoot App Server is a Node.js HTTP server. It serves your application build. So you should still do you normal build. But you replace the static web server with Ember FastBoot App Server. It's documentation contains a [Quick Start example](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-app-server#quick-start).